# List changes even though it's not being changed

Tags: python

```
Class A:
    def somefunction(self,somelist):

        print(str(somelist)) #Prints ["1","#2","3","#4"]

        b = B()
        filterlist = b.remove_tagfromarray(somelist)  

        print(str(somelist))  #Prints ["1","3"] #<<<<<WHY IS THIS?!!!!!!
        print(str(y))         #Prints ["1","3"]
```

remove_tagfromarray(x) takes in an array and returns an array without hashtags. However, after doing the code above it also alters the ORIGINAL array which was never operated on or referenced in the function called in the other class. I'm extremely confused. Even introducing a new variable doesn't seem to work.

```
Class A:
    def somefunction(self,somelist):

        savedarray = somelist
        print(str(somelist)) #Prints ["1","#2","3","#4"]

        b = B()
        filterlist = b.remove_tagfromarray(somelist)

        print(str(savedarray))  #Prints ["1","3"]  WHY!?!?!?!?
        print(str(filterlist))  #Prints ["1","3"]
```

as far as the function is concerned, it takes in the list as an argument, copies it to another "returnarray" variable, which is fiddled with until it is returned in the end. Mind you it works as I'm getting correct results, but somehow that function alters the original variable. Am I missing something here? Obviously somelist or savedarray (in the second example) should return the unaltered array.

```
def remove_tagfromarray(self,somelist,bannedchar="#"):
        popque = []
        popcount = 0
        n=0
        returnarray=somelist
        for word in returnarray:              
            if (bannedchar in word)):  
                popque.append(n)        
            n+=1

        for target in popque:            
            returnarray.pop(target-popcount)   
            popcount = popcount + 1

        return returnarray
```

Comment: It might possibly be helpful if you actually showed us the code of `remove_tagfromarray()`. That said, Python likes to pass objects by reference, so `savedarray = somelist` just creates a new reference to the same `list`.

Comment: Sorry, I added the code that removes the tag from the list (yes, I'm aware there might be a much better way to do this). It might very well be the pass objects by reference. If so, what can I do instead? I'll try reading the other thread and doing the splice method of creating the copied list.

Comment: Yes, creating a copy of the list, either in `filterwords()` or before you call it, should do it. The slice operator works for this: `returnarray = somelist[:]`

Comment: Read the linked question and its answers. It describes the exact same problem.

Comment: Yep,  `returnarray = somelist[:]` fixed it. Thanks for helping out a newbie like me :)

PS: How did you find the duplicate question so fast, seems like it would be hard to find an exact problem.

Comment: The beginner gotchas produce frequent questions and can therefore be recognized and resolved pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put,  lists can be passed around by reference.  Somewhere in code outside the listed code these lists are getting linked together by one referencing the other or something of a similar nature.

Answer (score 0):

```
returnarray=somelist
```

Python passes everything by reference. This line makes the two names `returnarray` and `somelist` refer to the **same** list. Everything you do to `returnarray` will be reflected in `somelist`.

Make a copy instead:

```
returnarray=somelist[:]
```